# How do we lock or embed a picture into a cell on XLS Jasper Report?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I am preparing a spreadsheet for a daycare by using Jasper.  We are populating every child's information and corresponding picture of the child with their parent in a single row. (ie) each row will have one child info with one cell having a image. When I am trying to filter or alphabetize by last name of the child, image does not follow the information in the row. Do we have a property in Jasper for embedding an image in to cell (part of the cell)?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work if you do xlsx instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate on this? Ms Excel 2007 has an option which embeds the image into a cell, (ie) “Move and size with cells”.  Is this option supported by jasper? Please advice.

Comment: It seems to be the default value when you export to the XSLX format, well at least when I tried it from iReport. I could not find anything specific in JasperReports for changing that setting though. So my assumption is that it is the default for when inserting an image in Excel. Sorry I don't having anything more, I tried to find some documentation about, but came up empty handed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with XSLX exporter, but didn't work. Please help me if any one has any solution for this.

Comment: This seems to be more of an excel problem than a jasper issue.. am I correct?

Comment: I think it is Jasper issue; XLS (Version 2007) has options for embedding an image into a cell or in floating mode.  But I didn’t see any property for an image in jasper for embedding.

Comment: @Naveen have you been able to find a solution for this problem?
i have the same issue also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next property string :

```
property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/
```

Or set it in your template properties:

```
property: net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics value: false
```

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports has the property [`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.image.anchor.type`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.image.anchor.type)  since version 5.0.4. For activating 'Move and size with cells' option in Excel you need to set this property to 'MoveSize' value.